# Node/add form don't working from page template

Tags: theming, nodes, forms

I put the node/add form in the page.tpl file:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = drupal_get_form('my_page_node_form', $node);
print drupal_render($form);
```

It is perfectly added and output in accordance with form_alter() function. The idea is that an anonymous user can create a node from custom page. From a 'node/add/my_page' page, this functionality works. But the other page does not work. My form_alter() for this:

```
  $form['title']['#access'] = user_access('administer my page node title');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
    '#weight' => 50,
    '#submit' => array('node_form_submit'),
  );
```

I do not see anything in the logs, and I do not see any messages. Why is it not saved?

Answer (score 0):

Then just use hook_node_submit() into your custom module.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7.x

(i.e)

```
function modulename_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
   if($node->type == 'node_machine_name'){
      //you code..
   }
}
```

And also if your submit button does not work then don't render submit button  instead use drupal_render_childern()

```
<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

Thank you.